# Gitlab runner has Permission denied error in mkdir

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I started gitlab runner with the following script:

```
gitlab-runner register --tls-ca-file="$GIT_CERTIFICATE_DIR" \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "https://${GIT_SERVER}/" \
    --registration-token "${GIT_RUNNER_TOKEN}" \
    --description "ionic gitlab runner" \
    --executor "shell" \
    --tag-list android,ios \
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner start
gitlab-runner run
```

when a job executes I get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)
  on ionic gitlab runner xmq8zWSZ
Using Shell executor...
Running on DEMU-MAC01.local...
mkdir: /Users/s.dutta/Workspace/builds/xmq8zWSZ/0/xx/yy-app.tmp: Permission denied
mkdir: /Users/s.dutta/Workspace/builds/xmq8zWSZ/0/xx/yy-app.tmp: Permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you tried with another working directory? `gitlab-runner run --working-directory "/some/other/dir"`

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the respective gitlab-runner service is not running with the required permissions (admin rights), check the priviledges. Screenshot for services of a GitLab Runner running on a Windows host: [image: Screenshot Windows services]